# PHP - I am trying to grant access to page ONLY if the user's rank is 1

Tags: php

Thank you everyone who will try to help me.

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    require("inc/connection.php"); 
    require("inc/common.php"); 
    if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) { 
        //header("Location: login.php");
        exit('No Session');
    }
    $query = "SELECT rank FROM users WHERE `username` =  ? and `rank` = 1";
    $result = mysqli_prepare($link, $query);
    echo "SELECT rank FROM users WHERE `username` = '" . $_SESSION['user']['username'] . "' and `rank` = 1";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, 's', $_SESSION['user']['username']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {
        //header("Location: login.php");
        exit('User Doesnt have one rank');
    }
?>
```

I have a tried a lot... My friend helped me a bit. But he couldnt get it to work. So basically the `$Link` variable is the connection. the `$_SESSION_[user]` is the session of the logged in user.

My first error is:

> **Warning: mysqli_query():** Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 5

I don't know why this one is happening its just not getting the rank for some reason (I think).

My second error is because of my syntax because I am fairly new on php I tried googling it I went on teh php guide and added `MYSQLI_BOTH` because it requires 2 parameters but tehre was only 1 but that didnt fix it but heres the error:

> **Warning:** mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
require("inc/connection.php"); 
require("inc/common.php"); 
if(empty($_SESSION['user']['username'])) { 
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
$result = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT rank FROM users WHERE `username` = ? and `rank` = 1");
$result->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['user']['username']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
$result->store_result();
if($result->num_rows() < 1) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

Note the prepared statement usage which separates the user input from your query. For more information on prepared statements see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Previously your query was invalid because `$_SESSION[user]` was a string and needed to be quoted. With prepared statements this is handled for you.

Also it is more efficient to have the SQL check the rank.

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 4

Comment: These are all caused by the initial failure which is usage of the `mysqli` connection. Where do you assign `$link`?

Comment: in connection.php $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

Comment: Do you check that `$link` is connected?

Comment: yes if (!$link) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 
 mysqli_close($link);

Comment: Take out the `mysqli_close($link);`.

Comment: It redirects me to login.php when my rank is 1.

Comment: The session is set? Added debugging lines. Where is `header` firing from?

Comment: Like am I logged in? If so yes.

Comment: With added debugging lines what do you get? `User Doesnt have one rank`?

Comment: The if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) { is the if statement that redirects me to login.php

Comment: Okay, if you output this code and run the query does it return a result on DB?

Comment: When I look on the page it says: SELECT rank FROM users WHERE `username` = 'Array' and `rank` = 1 and User Doesnt have one rank  and Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 13

Comment: So `$_SESSION['user']` is an array? Try `print_r($_SESSION['user']);`.

Comment: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 11 and SELECT rank FROM users WHERE `username` = 'Array' and `rank` = 1Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => admin )

Comment: Okay, so you are using the wrong assignment. Should be `$_SESSION['user']['username']`.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 11

Comment: There's only one placeholder and one variable that error doesn't make sense to me. You are using the above code?

Comment: I also get this on line 13: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 13

Comment: when i do that it says: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\wamp\www\RoLuck\adminpanel.php on line 10

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this is the solution that you are looking for

```
if((isset($_SESSION['user'])) && ($row['rank'] == 1)) { 
    header("Location: login.php");
    die("Redirecting to login.php");
}
```

Comment: theres still an error with this line: while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION[user]` is not a valid syntax. It should be `$_SESSION['user']`.

Please try this updated code.

```
<?php 
    require("inc/connection.php"); 
    require("inc/common.php"); 

    if((empty($_SESSION['user'])) || (!isset($_SESSION)))
    {
        echo "Nothing inside session variable";
    }
    else
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT rank FROM users WHERE `username` =   "' . $_SESSION['user'] . '"');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        if(empty($_SESSION['user']) || $row['rank'] == 1) { 
            header("Location: login.php");
            die("Redirecting to login.php");
        } 
    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: @RobertWills
I've modified my code a bit. Try again.